# Upgrading from php5 to php7

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I upgraded from php5 to php7. In php5 the code below works. After I upgrade to php7 this function no longer works. Please advise and give me solution. I appreciate your answer.

```
session_start();
    include "config/koneksi.php";
    $sid = session_id();
    // fungsi untuk mendapatkan isi keranjang belanja
    function isi_keranjang(){
        $isikeranjang = array();
        $sid = session_id();
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM orders_temp_sby WHERE id_session='$sid'");

        while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $isikeranjang[] = $r;
        }
        return $isikeranjang;
    }  

    $tgl_skrg = date("Ymd");
    $jam_skrg = date("H:i:s");
    // Login utk SBY Stationery
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT USRID FROM mst_user WHERE USRNAME='$email' AND USRPWD='$password' AND blokir='N'"));

    // mendapatkan nomor kustomer
    $id_kustomer=$id[USRID];

    // simpan data pemesanan 
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO orders_sby(tgl_order,jam_order,id_kustomer,terkirim) VALUES('$tgl_skrg','$jam_skrg','$id_kustomer','0000-00-00')");

    // mendapatkan nomor orders
    $id_orders=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    // panggil fungsi isi_keranjang dan hitung jumlah produk yang dipesan
    $isikeranjang = isi_keranjang();
    $jml          = count($isikeranjang);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $jml; $i++)
    {
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO orders_detail_sby(id_orders,id_produk,jumlah) VALUES('$id_orders',{$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']},{$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})");
    }
```

Comment: What errors do you receive? Looks like `$conn` might have a variable scope issue. You also should parameterize your queries and it is likely that `for` and `query` should be rewritten.

Comment: Paste the error you get putting at the top this: `ini_set("display_errors"); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: user3783242 >>> For this problem cannot insert to table orders_detail_sby previously I used php5 query can work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using an [array key that is being considered a CONSTANT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts):

```
$id_kustomer=$id[USRID];
```

Try changing this to:

```
$id_kustomer=$id['USRID'];
```

You might also review [what php.net has to say about array index quoting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts).  I'll copy a bit here for you:

> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, `$foo['bar']` is correct, while `$foo[bar]` is not.

Comment: For my code doesn't work is :

 for ($i = 0; $i < $jml; $i++)
    {
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO orders_detail_sby(id_orders,id_produk,jumlah) VALUES('$id_orders',{$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']},{$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})");
    }

Comment: How do you know that is the line?  Can you paste your php error, please?  I can guarantee you that in PHP7 this `$id[USRID]` is returning something that you don't want.

Comment: Because for $id_kustomer=$id['USRID']; can insert for orders_sby

Only "FOR" condition cannot insert to table orders_detail_sby

Sorry I'm newbie..

Comment: i suggest you make this change.  ```$query = "INSERT INTO orders_detail_sby (id_orders, id_produk,jumlah) VALUES('$id_orders', {$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']},{$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})";``` and then try ```die($query);```.  Run your query to see the error.  After you fix it, then use ```mysqli_query($conn, $query);```

Comment: I try your suggestion cannot insert to Table :

for ($i = 0; $i < $jml; $i++)
  {
   $query = "INSERT INTO orders_detail_sby (id_orders, id_produk,jumlah) VALUES('$id_orders', {$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']},{$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})";
   mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  }


For PHP5 this coding can work.

Comment: so, The purpose of putting your query in `$query` is so that **you can use `die($query);`** to get the query.  Once you get the query, **use your _MySQL Client_ to manually run the query**.  I'm sure the problem will appear.  The `die($query);` is just a debugging step to find out why the query won't run.

Comment: Thank you for your response WEBjuju..Can you help me, where do I put die($query) for my condition? I appreciate it for your help.

Comment: ```$query = "INSERT INTO orders_detail_sby (id_orders, id_produk,jumlah) VALUES('$id_orders', {$isikeranjang[$i]['id_produk']},{$isikeranjang[$i]['jumlah']})"; die($query);```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for your help. I try to my problem used mysqli_fetch_array and I loop for data after that insert for my table. Once again thank you very much.